# Error pops up when trying to execute hdfs zkfc command

Tags: java, hadoop

Hi could anyone help me out im a newbie to hadoop wanted to try this feature out.so can anyone of you help.Im running on a single node cluster.

```
$ hdfs zkfc
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException: HA is not enabled for this namenode.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController.setConf(DFSZKFailoverController.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController.main(DFSZKFailoverController.java:168)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start

$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby

$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start

$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-zkfc start

This is for configuring NN.And it works!! Thanks
```

Comment: Issue `HA is not enabled for this namenode` persists in CDH4 after execution of these commands. [New Question](http://serverfault.com/questions/604056/unable-to-convert-hdfs-from-non-ha-to-ha) regarding this opened at ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

The error speaks for itself: looks like you forgot to change a setting hadoop uses.

Comment: Thank you!! it says "HA is not enabled for this namenode".Could you  please help me to configure my namenode.

Comment: The hadoop docs at http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HDFSHighAvailability.html say a lot about what HA is in the hadoop way and how to configure it.